# Materials for a person with math background to enter quantum information theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, mathematical-physics, book-recommendation

I am interesting in mathematical and theoretic approaches in quantum information theory. I have backgrounds with basic group representation theory(I study this for my master degree) and some fundamental analysis(such as measure theory, $L^{p}$ space), just something everyone will learn in real analysis course. But I have less knowledge with functional analysis and complex analysis(just in undergraduate level). I want to find some materials(with mathematical viewpoint and abstract structure might be better) to enter this field. Are there any advices?

Answer (score 0):

I think your background should be absolutely sufficient to understand the basics of quantum information theory. Mostly, linear algebra is used.

The standard text book is Nielsen, Chuang: "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information". Another nice reference, a bit more mathematically rigourously, is by Kitaev et al: "Classical and Quantum Computation".